# Why is it possible to delete "or" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, ellipses

> He plays it well,(or) at least better than you.

I am told by aparente001 that it is possible to omit "or" in this sentence.
But I am not quite sure how it is possible. Can any of you guys explain?

Comment: In speech it is often missed out, there is the assumption that it is understood. In effect you're saying "He plays it well. At least - better than you." The **dash** stands in for "he's plays it" - "He plays it well. At least, he plays it better than you." But if in doubt, don't omit it.

Comment: According to your explanation, it's only possible in speech? Then I cannot actually write it?

Comment: As it's addressed to 'you', it's hard to see when you would be writing it, unless in a letter to someone - in which case it's like a conversation, so you can be as informal as you like, depending on who you are addressing. Or, if you were writing fiction and giving these words to a character, you can write whatever you like. But suppose it was about a 3rd person, eg writing a school report - "He plays it well, or at least better than the other children." It would be best to include 'or' in more formal written work.

Comment: Note that if you omit 'or' it's best to punctuate it differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what "or" means in this sentence:

**I would like a red hat or a blue hat.**

Now consider what "or" means in this sentence:

**He's a doctor — or so he said.**

In the hat example, "or" refers to options or choices; in the doctor example, it comments upon the statement itself: he may not be a doctor.  The speaker is *hedging*.

The same sort of hedging occurs in "at least better than you". He might not play well; his playing is merely better than yours.

When commenting upon the statement one has made by tacking on a hedging remark, we do not require "or" to connect the two statements:

**He plays it well — at least better than you do.**

There is a syntactic pause after "well", and the intonational contours of "at least better than you do" would corroborate its function as a hedging afterthought. The *asyndeton* does not obscure the syntax; we still know that "at least better than you do" is a predicate complement, replacing "well".

Comment: So is it called asyndeton? Is it the rule used?

Comment: You could dress up everyone who calls it asyndeton in clown costumes and  stuff them into a small car at the circus,